# Updating Managed fields

Tags: managed-package

I have a checkbox in a custom object in an un-managed package. I will set it to editable in the profile, but read only on a page layout. My logic sets it to ‘true’ within the app.  Procedurally, the customer/user will need to reset it to false outside of the app.

When it becomes a managed app:

1)  Will the user be able to write an apex trigger to reset it to false?
2)  Can the user write a workflow on my custom object?

Comment: Both options are possible. Triggers and flows run in system context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, subscribers can always create workflow rules, triggers, and flows that access managed package fields and objects.

Comment: To test the trigger, I'm executing an update in Execute Anonymous.  My test works on standard objects (Contact), but it doesn't recognize my custom object (Project).    List<Project> projs = [SELECT Id FROM Project Where Project.PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = True];
for(Project project :projs){
    Project.PT_PIPROJ__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = False;
}

update projs;

Comment: @Stan The names use the `__` notation, as `NS__Object__c` or `NS__Field__c`.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the code (below).  I now get the error: 'Invalid character in identifier: PI_SFINT__Project__c'.  Part of my problem is that I don't know what line 2 is doing.  Can you translate it for me?     for(PI_SFINT__Project__c  PI_SFINT__Project__c :projs){  ?  Here's the fully modified code.        List<PI_SFINT__Project__c> projs = [SELECT Id FROM PI_SFINT__Project__c Where PI_SFINT__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = True];
for(PI_SFINT__Project__c  PI_SFINT__Project__c :projs){
    PI_SFINT__Project__c.PI_SFINT__PI_Outbound_Msg_Sent__c = False;
}

update projs;

Comment: @Stan identifiers can't have double underscores in them. `PI_SFINT__Project__c project` would be better.